# SQLCMD - stored procedure returns incomplete results

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file, stored-procedures, sqlcmd

I recently started automating some stuff using batch scripts. Currently I have a stored procedure which stages CSVs from a certain folder. This stored procedure runs well on it's on in SSMS.

When running:

1. SSMS - `exec IMPORT_CSV_FROM_FOLDER 'filepath'` - *1576140* records
2. CMD - `sqlcmd -h-1 -S SERVERNAME -d DATABASE_STAGING -o logfile.log -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON; exec IMPORT_CSV_FROM_FOLDER 'FILEPATH'"` - *1576140* records
3. BATCH - `sqlcmd -h-1 -S %SERVER% -d %ENVIRONMENT%_STAGING -o logfile.log -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON; exec IMPORT_CSV_FROM_FOLDER @FILEPATH=$(val)" -v val='%STAGEM%'` - *different values every time* records

Comment: Why are you invoking `SQLCMD` differently in the batch file than from the command prompt?  It seems to me that's likely where you're getting different results.

Comment: Just tried this:
`sqlcmd -h-1 -S %SERVER% -d %ENVIRONMENT%_STAGING -o logfile.log -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON; exec IMPORT_CSV_FROM_FOLDER '%STAGEM%'"` and it worked. I thought that I had to parametrize SP in the way give in OP.